# Spring Boot/RabbitMQ avoid unack msg

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-integration, spring-integration-amqp

```
@RabbitListener(queues="XYZ")
public void rabbitMsgReceiver(@Payload final UserProfile up, Message msg, Channel channel)  {

}
```

If the message that is received is not a valid JSON of `UserProfile`, then `ListenerExecutionFailedException` occurs and the message goes to the 
unack state. How can I send the message into the dead letter queue?

Comment: Are you sure it goes into unack state instead of being rejected and disappearing from the queue?

Comment: You should not use MANUAL acks; let the container handle the acks. A message conversion exception is considered fatal and will be routed to the DLQ, by default.

Comment: @AdamMichalik yes it is going to the unack state.

Comment: @GaryRussell if i don't use MANUAL ack and use AUTO ack then this msg never goes to the dead letter queue. Msg remins into the ready state and Listener received this again and again and throw exception.

Comment: Please show the stack trace - with the default error handler, if the exception cause chain contains a `MessageConversionException` it is treated as fatal and the message is rejected instead of nack'd.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a dead letter queue policy in order to send unacked message to dlq instead of putting them to the original queue

https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html#using-policies

example for your queue XYZ, suppose your set XYZ-dlq for it :

```
sudo rabbitmqctl set_policy XYZ-dlq "^XYZ$" '{"dead-letter-exchange":"", "dead-letter-routing-key":"XYZ-dlq"}' --apply-to queues
```